# SQL full-text search: How to remove specific word-breaker characters

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find out how to remove a specific character from the list of word-breakers used in full-text searching (English-US).  The hyphen is the character causing me problems.  When I search for ABC-DEF, SQL returns records containing ABC or DEF.  I need this to return only those records that contain the full ABC-DEF words.

Can I remove word-breaker characters from the list of word-breakers?  If not, is there a specific way to write this query to return only those records that contain the whole (hyphenated) word? Or, is there a configuration parameter I can change?

Comment: What's the code for your search? Have you tried something like `...WHERE CONTAINS(col, '"ABC-DEF"')`, i.e. using "quoting" to search for the exact phrase?

Comment: Yes we tried that (quoting).  Our query is dynamic so it varies in form.  The consistent thing is that if searching for "ABC-DEF" we locate records containing just "ABC" or "DEF".  I've looked into "noise" characters and word-breakers and have not found the answer there.

Comment: We are working with SQL Server 2008 R2.  I find that if we upgrade to SQL Server 2014, our problem apparently disappears.  I will look into that option for our production.  Thanks Matt for your interest in our problem.

Comment: No problem. If the upgrade does solve your problem (I'm guessing it would be due to bug fixes or improvements in the language-processing packs) then you should add that [as an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it as accepted, as it might help other people in the same situation.